# Ubuntu Pro tab in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu-pro

I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 from 22.04 I have a subscription to Ubuntu Pro and whereas in 22.04 there was an Ubuntu Pro tab in Software & Updates, this is not the case in Ubuntu 23.04 so I wonder why? or I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Pro is only available for LTS releases. V23.04 is not LTS

The next version for Pro will be 24.04

[Reference](https://www.ghacks.net/2023/01/31/ubuntu-pro-is-now-available-here-is-what-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: Thank you 'graham' for your comment. However I wonder why release 22.04 - which is not an LTS release - had such a tab. Anyway, I'm not sure whether or not we're talking about the same thing, I mean, Pro is available for Ubuntu being this LTS or not; the point is a tab in Software & Updates.

Comment: v22.04 is actually an LTS version [see this reference](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)

Comment: Sorry, you're right regarding LTS releases. But Pro is available in 23.04 (I have a subscription), or did you mean  the Ubuntu Pro tab is only available for LTS releases?